# Hibernate Search- Select Query SQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I am trying to run the below query in Hibernate Search and I am getting the below exception in the log. I am not sure what I am missing to make it work.

```java
String hsql="SELECT * FROM (SELECT dest.ID,dest.postal_code AS ZIP, ACOS(SIN ( RADIANS( src.latitude) ) * SIN ( RADIANS ( dest.latitude )) + COS ( RADIANS ( src.latitude)) * COS ( RADIANS ( dest.latitude )) * COS ( RADIANS( src.longitude ) - RADIANS ( dest.longitude ))) * 3959 AS DISTANCE FROM post_codes dest CROSS JOIN post_codes src WHERE src.ID = ( SELECT ID FROM post_codes WHERE postal_code = :zipCode GROUP BY ID ) AND ( dest.ID <> src.ID OR  dest.ID = src.ID )) HAVING DISTANCE <= :miles GROUP BY ID,ZIP,DISTANCE;ORDER BY DISTANCE";

org.hibernate.SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery(hsql);
query.setParameter("zipCode", 60195);
query.setParameter("miles", 5);

List list= query.list(); 
System.out.println("***************"+list.size());
```

Exception in the log

```
16:24:34,387 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 911, SQLState: 22019
16:24:34,387 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] ORA-00911: invalid character
16:24:34,409 ERROR [[spring]] Servlet.service() for servlet spring threw exception
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two mistakes in `SQL` query.Firstly you must remove semicolon before `order by` and `having` clause always must be after `group by` clause.Your code must be following:

```
String hsql="SELECT * FROM (SELECT dest.ID,dest.postal_code AS ZIP, ACOS(SIN ( RADIANS( src.latitude) ) * SIN ( RADIANS ( dest.latitude )) + COS ( RADIANS ( src.latitude)) * COS ( RADIANS ( dest.latitude )) * COS ( RADIANS( src.longitude ) - RADIANS ( dest.longitude ))) * 3959 AS DISTANCE FROM post_codes dest CROSS JOIN post_codes src WHERE src.ID = ( SELECT ID FROM post_codes WHERE postal_code = :zipCode GROUP BY ID ) AND ( dest.ID <> src.ID OR  dest.ID = src.ID )) GROUP BY ID,ZIP,DISTANCE HAVING DISTANCE <= :miles ORDER BY DISTANCE";
```

Comment: Thx .I got it fixed it is working But the query is very slow to retrieve the result .If you can help in fine tuning the query that would be great

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove semicolon from hsql.

Comment: When i remove semicolon at the end it is complaining Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement